# resending mouse/keyboard input

Tags: windows, hook

I'm trying to duplicate mouse/keyboard control on 2 computers. The plan was to a) capture mouse/keyboard events on the host using SetWindowsHookEx, transfer the required parameters via network to the other computer and then play back using.. something. I'm not very familiar with the windows api so I need help with the following:

As far as I understand, the callback set in SetWindowsHookEx receives pointers wParam and lParam that refer to data that should contain all that I need. Is the data that they point to always the same length? Or if not, how can I find out what type they are pointing to?

Next, is there a way to send out the same data described in wParam and lParam on the receiving computer? I did find mouse_event and keyboard_event but I think those are for constructing input from the scratch and would require me to disassemble the wParam/lParam data and recreate it.